# How to add a service to the workbench's left menu and execute it?

Tags: hiconic

I modelled a service request without any parameters required (neither user nor implicit). It returns a list of `Holiday` instances.

```
GetHolidays extends ServiceRequest {
    @Override
    EvalContext<Holiday> eval(Evaluator<ServiceRequest> evaluator);
}
```

How do I need to design my managed folder instance inside my initializer so that the service gets auto-executed when I click on this menu entry?

```
@Managed
private Folder holidaysAction() {
    Folder bean = create(Folder.T).initFolder("holidays", "Holidays");
    bean.setIcon(icons.holidayIcon());
    
    // TODO add code for GetHolidays here
    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the request prototype based `com.braintribe.model.workbench.ServiceRequestAction`:

```java
ServiceRequestAction action = create(ServiceRequestAction.T);
GetHolidays request = create(GetHolidays.T);
action.setRequest(request);
action.setDisplayName(create(LocalizedString.T).putDefault("Get Holidays"));
action.setExecutionType(ExecutionType.auto);

bean.setAction(action);
```